# Spring MVC and 302 Status

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.2 and have simple controllers like this

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index (ModelAndView modelAndView) {
       // some code here
    }
```

and..

```
@Controller
public class AnotherController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/another/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView anotherPageView (ModelAndView modelAndView) {
       // some code here
    }
```

if I try open page `/another/error` I get 404 error - this is ok, but when I open page with url like `/blabla` i have a 302 Status and redirect to main page ("/").

Why? How can I get 404 error on any page who not mapped in any controllers in my application ?

Comment: you must have a mapping or something even before spring starts handling the request that returns 302. Returning 404 is the default behaviour.

Comment: >>you must have a mapping or something even before spring starts handling the request that returns 302. But how i can do that?

Comment: @jToM please post your web.xml and spring configuration files (that are the typical places where such a redirect is configured) - I expect that this redirect is not obvious but a side effect of one of the configured components. -- And do you have other controllers than this?

Comment: i'm solved that, just a have a several controller with root mapping. Thx for answer.